# How to open Trusted web activity from our Activity by sending URL

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

in documents From manifest we can set URL to Trusted web activity. But how to open from our activity by sending URL to Trusted web activity?

1. Can we manipulate click events in trusted web Activity?

Comment: Hi. If I understood correctly, you have an existing native Activity and want to launch the TWA from it.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

"how to open from our activity by sending URL to Trusted web activity": for the ones who are still looking for the answer - please see my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58069713/8818281

In short:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity.class);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("ANOTHER_SITE_URL"));
startActivity(intent);
```